# Decompose a Quantum Circuit in Cirq

Tags: linear-algebra, quantum-computing, cirq

I am working on Cirq and need to perform certain unitary operations on qubits. For that, I am using the `MatrixGate()` function in Cirq. Unlike Qiskit, I could not find any function like decompose or transpile to simplify the Unitary operation into basic U3 and CNOT gates.

For instance, if I want to act the following Unitary Operator,

[Unitary Operator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QY3si.png)

To do this I use this code in Qiskit. Looking for something equivalent in Cirq.

```
qc=QuantumCircuit(2)
qc.unitary(U,[0,1])
qc=transpile(qc,basis_gates=['cx','u3'])
qc.draw(output='mpl')
```

[Unitary Gate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gmvr.png)

After using Transpile function in Qiskit

[Transpiled Unitary Gate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRKJL.png)

I even tried to work up the Cosine-Sine Decomposition Algorithm which Qiskit uses to decompose these Unitary Operations. As mentioned in the paper, [Quantum Circuits for Isometries](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.06911.pdf), but they do not trivially yield the required decomposition. 
Please help by either suggesting :

1. Some code in Cirq to decompose circuits or
2. A workaround to export Qiksit circuits to Cirq or
3. A simpler algorithm to decompose Unitary Operations.

Comment: Just wondering, why are you needing to go to cirq?

Comment: @met927 I am working on Tensor-flow Quantum which uses cirq backend to create a quantum circuit. TFQ does not accept MatrixGate() and hence I wanted to decompose it into simpler gates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An example of such a method is  `cirq.two_qubit_matrix_to_operations`. It uses the kak decomposition (cartan decomposition) to determine how to translate a unitary matrix into a series of operations with minimal number of CZ gates.

```
import cirq

desired_matrix = cirq.testing.random_unitary(dim=4)

synthesized_operations = cirq.two_qubit_matrix_to_operations(
    cirq.LineQubit(0),
    cirq.LineQubit(1),
    desired_matrix,
    allow_partial_czs=False,
)
circuit = cirq.Circuit(synthesized_operations)

synthesized_matrix = cirq.unitary(circuit)

cirq.testing.assert_allclose_up_to_global_phase(
    desired_matrix,
    synthesized_matrix,
    atol=1e-4
)

print(desired_matrix.round(3))
print(circuit)
```

Prints (for example):

```
[[ 0.234-0.169j -0.81 +0.038j -0.327+0.138j -0.364-0.029j]
 [-0.503-0.407j  0.221-0.206j  0.063+0.144j -0.629-0.264j]
 [ 0.271+0.338j  0.337-0.128j -0.343+0.731j -0.165+0.052j]
 [ 0.504+0.236j  0.222+0.269j  0.244-0.371j -0.608-0.043j]]
0: ───PhX(-0.283)^0.631───@───PhX(0.673)^0.5────@───PhX(-0.375)^0.5───@───PhX(0.827)^0.147───Z^-0.269───
                          │                     │                     │
1: ───PhX(0.508)^0.338────@───PhX(0.65)^(5/6)───@───PhX(0.65)^0.995───@───PhX(0.302)^0.512───Z^-0.516───
```